How to reconcile bond duration with yield responses in Long-Term vs Short-Term bonds?
I'm struggling to reconcile two aspects of bond behavior in response to interest rate changes:

Longer-term bonds have higher durations, implying greater sensitivity to interest rate changes, which should significantly affect their prices.

Despite this, shorter-term bonds often show quicker and more pronounced adjustments in their yields in response to interest rate expectations.


How can these two observations be squared?

Your question refers to "interest rates" without specifying which interest rates you are talking about.  Short and long term bonds are priced relative to short and long term interest rates which are often different and can change over time in different ways.
If you had the same change (say a 50 basis point increase) in the interest rates on one year bonds and ten year bonds, the effect of that change on the price of existing 10 year bonds would be larger than the effect on the price of existing one year bonds because of the longer duration.
However, you don't normally expect to see short and long term interest rates changing in lock step. Your two observations are completely consistent with a world in which short term interest rates are more volatile than long term interest rates.
Keep in mind, that in the US, short term interest rates are effectively controlled and set by the Fed, while long term interest rates are set more by market expectations.    The result is that the yield curve may range from the normal situation in which long term interest rates are higher to the current ("inverted") situation in which short term interest rates are higher than long term rates.

The key is to distinguish price and yield. Duration measures the sensitivity of a bonds price to interest rate changes. Yield is in some sense synonymous with interest rates - meaning it's the interest (coupon) rate that you would get on a equivalent bond that traded at its par value.
As interest rate expectations change, bond yields change in tandem with those expectations, so yields are affected more than prices.
In other words, a short-term bond's yield can change drastically without affecting its price as much (because its duration is lower), while a small change in interest rates can have larger impacts on the price of long-term bonds.
